# Problems with tools that validate if text and buttons break on device screens

Tags: android, ios, mobile, automation, automated-tests

I'm researching Mobile automated tests further that I can validate if the elements are actually on my device screen.

I noticed that Appium (ui automator on Android and xcode on ios) validates only the functionality and location of the elements on the page, but doesn't check if the element text is partially displayed on the device.

Am I correct with this statement about Appium?

I also researched about Espresso. Can this tool validate what I need? And for ios?

The main objective is to check if the texts and buttons do not break on the screen of the different devices that I validate...

I look forward and thank you !!!

Comment: if I am not wrong, are you want to verify the text of button?

Comment: Hi, @Mani!

The validation text on the button is possible with Appium, because the text is located on the element! 

I want to validate if this text located in the element is actually being displayed on the device screen, got it?

Comment: can you give some example above description, so that I can help you

Comment: Of course!!

The text "abcd" in the element "t" is displayed correctly. However, it is incomplete on device type "x" (only "abc" is displayed, "d" is not displayed ").

This scenario could happen, correct?

Comment: can anybody help me???

Comment: "This scenario could happen, correct?" If you mean that text could go "over" the view and only show then "abc" insted of "abcd" is yes possibile. Espresso can check that this specific text is on place, or verify that sting is correct "abcd". I can post answer how to check this with Espresso, if you decide to do it by that. But I'm sure Appium + Robot Framework can easily check that stuff too.

Comment: @polnkape,
Very thanks for your answer! Helped me a lot!